# How to run a segmented quantile regression in R?

Tags: r, quantile-regression

I am trying to fit a "constraint line" to a bi-variate scattergram using quantile regression in R. My response variable (`WaterEr`) represents annual soil loss and my independent variable represents (`RainfallEr`) rainfall erosivity (see plot below).
[image]

The result I would like to achieve is based on a range of publications from [Hao et al. 2017](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.agee.2017.02.015) where the values on the x-axis are equally divided in 100 parts (or bins) to create 100 columns (see below). Then, they use segmented quantile regression to define as many boundary points as there are columns to fit the constraint line. For information, they used Origin 9 (OriginLabs, USA) to run these calculations.
[image]

As the response doesn't seem to be linear, I have tried to apply a non-linear quantile regression with the `nlrq()` function from the `quantreg::` package.
Here is a sample of the code I have applied:

```
library(quantreg)

# create a dummy range of rainfall erosivity that we use to predict soil erosion from our fitted model
predict_range <- data.frame(RainfallEr = seq(26, 6000, length = 10000))


# visualise part of the data.frame (first 20 rows, thre are 188,000 rows in total)
combined_df <- data.frame(x = c(-100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354, -100099.882870354),
                y = c(6309106.01324476, 6309606.01324476, 6310106.01324476, 6313106.01324476, 6313606.01324476, 6314106.01324476, 6314606.01324476, 6315106.01324476, 6315606.01324476, 6316106.01324476, 6316606.01324476, 6317106.01324476, 6317606.01324476, 6318106.01324476, 6318606.01324476, 6319106.01324476, 6319606.01324476, 6320106.01324476, 6320606.01324476, 6321106.01324476),
                WaterEr = c(0.00868059950549645, 0.0091251355161706, 0.0326287519829422, 0.000178796614549174, 4.91241536357219e-05, 4.85026861560795e-05, 5.04674993751928e-05, 4.08148993464175e-05, 4.00002440967491e-05, 4.33874760799851e-05, 3.69049351915739e-05, 7.04070050153354e-05, 0.00103683921729508, 0.0172595102342795, 0.0162371833835457, 0.0166259941567392, 0.0170966498768553, 0.0143875260855259, 0.00268803246521925, 0.00201286512639929), 
                RainfallEr = c(220.511938095093, 220.511938095093, 271.830009102821, 266.356387972832, 266.356387972832, 266.356387972832, 276.096389293671, 276.096389293671, 276.096389293671, 281.761203408241, 281.761203408241, 281.761203408241, 246.739157915115, 246.739157915115, 246.739157915115, 210.058827996254, 210.058827996254, 210.058827996254, 180.8417532444, 180.8417532444), 
                Year = c("2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007"))
 

# Test 1: with polynomial order equation
my.equation <- WaterEr ~ a * RainfallEr^2 + b * RainfallEr  + c

test_nlrq <- nlrq(my.equation, data = combined_df, start = list(a = 0.01, b = 1, c = 0.6), tau = 0.9) # note the a, b, and c values are chosen randomly
# summary(test_nlrq)

my.line90 <- within(predict_range, 
             WaterEr <- predict(test_nlrq, 
                            newdata = predict_range))


# Test 2: with nlrq with automatic SSlogis() function
test_nlrq2 <- nlrq(WaterEr ~ SSlogis(RainfallEr, Asym, mid, scal), data = combined_df, tau = 0.9)
#summary(test_nlrq2 )

my.line90_v2 <- within(predict_range, 
             WaterEr <- predict(test_nlrq2, 
                            newdata = predict_range))
# plot the results (see attachment below)
plot(WaterEr ~ RainfallEr, data = combined_df, pch = 16, cex = 0.5, 
     xlab = "Rainfall erosivity (MJ.mm/ha/h/y)", ylab = "Annual water erosion (t/ha/y)")
lines(WaterEr ~ RainfallEr, data = my.line90, col = "red", lty = 2)
lines(WaterEr ~ RainfallEr, data = my.line90_v2, col = "blue", lty = 2)
legend("topright", legend = c("non-linear rq - poly", "non-linear rq - autoSSlogis"), col = c("red", "blue"), lty = 2)
```

Plot produced with `quantreg::` package:
[image]

As you can probably see, the regression lines from the `nlrq()` functions I have tested don't look anything like the published diagram.

Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(combined_df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(combined_df, 20))`.

Comment: Thank you @Rui Barradas. I have updated the code to provide a sample of the dataset (20 rows out of 188000).
This is my very first post and I haven't figured out all the tricks about posting on StackOverflow.